# User Disappears in Vue and Firebase Project when I refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

my code is below

```
// getUser.js

import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config.js'

const user = ref(projectAuth.currentUser)

projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged( _user => {
  user.value = _user
  console.log("User available")
})

const getUser = () => {
  return ( user )
}

export default getUser;
```

```
// Account.vue
<template>
  <h3 v-if="user">Welcome</h3>
</template>

<script>
import getUser from '../composables/getUser.js'

export default {
  setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();
    console.log(user)

    return { user }
  }
  
}
</script>
```

When I refresh, the Welcome does not appear. And the console.log appear as this
[image]

May I know whether I am doing my code right? Since it seems like the v-if is not updating despite me getting a new user value. Thanks!

Comment: Your `getUser` function directly returns a ref to the user structure, but you are trying to destructure in the assignment here: `const { user } = getUser();`. Since the ref object has no `user` property, your `user` variable is always undefined. Instead try `const user = getUser();`.

Comment: Hello, thanks that solved my issue! Spent an hour plus on it turns out it's my fundamental is still not there yet. Thanks again pal!

Comment: That sounds like an answer @kdau! :-D